# Color HLSL DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm new to directX11,i want to color my triangle so here is my VertexShader:

```
PS_IN main( float4 pos : POSITION ,float4 color:COLOR) 
{
    PS_IN OUT;
    OUT.color = color;
    OUT.pos = pos;
    return OUT;
}
```

and PS:

```
float4 main(PS_IN OUT) : SV_TARGET
{
    return OUT.color;
}
```

Not that PS_IN is a struct like this:

```
struct PS_IN
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};
```

what's wrong with it? it shows absolutely nothing!

Comment: Provide us with more code. Show us a vertex buffer (coordinates of triangle)? Basically, show the code where you set vertex shader, pixel shader, init vertex buffer, calling of drawprimitives etc?

Comment: Debugging graphics programs is challenging because you can get the result of 'nothing shows up' for a large number of reasons. A few things to try: (1) Enable the Direct3D 11 [Debug layer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) and look for diagnostic messages, (2) Use Visual Studio [Graphics Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873207.aspx), or (3) use an existing working [tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef) and modify it one step at a time to understand how it works.

Comment: You may also want to look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) as a collection of useful Direct3D 11 utility code that you can use directly and/or explore for working sample code.

Answer (score 0):

here is more detail:
my input layout description and vertex struct:

```
struct Vertex
{
    Vertex();
    XMFLOAT3 pos;
    XMFLOAT4 color;
    Vertex(float x, float y, float z,float cr,float cg,float cb,float ca) : pos(x, y, z),color(cr,cg,cb,ca){}
};

D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC IED[]=
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
};
```

and here is vertices:

```
Vertex vertices[] =
    {
        Vertex(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f),
        Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f),
        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f),
    };
```

Triangle displayed perfectly just before i add color to it.